# How to compute $t_0$ and $r^0$ in Belavin-Drinfeld's classification of solutions of classical Yang-Baxter equations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-groups, integrable-systems, yang-baxter-equations

I tried to understand Belavin-Drinfeld's classification of solutions of classical Yang-Baxter equations.

In the book [a guide to quantum groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521558840), on page 83, there is an example of solutions of the classical Yang-Baxter equation in the case of $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_3$.

[image]

My questions are

(1) how to compute $t_0$ and $r^0$?

(2) In the case of (b), suppose that
\begin{align}
r^0 = \frac{1}{3} H_{\alpha} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\beta}.
\end{align} 
I tried to verify that
\begin{align}
r_{12}^0 + r_{21}^0 = t_0, \\
(\alpha \otimes 1)(r^0) + (1 \otimes \beta)(r^0) = 0.
\end{align}
We have 
\begin{align}
r_{12}^0 = r^0 = \frac{1}{3} H_{\alpha} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\beta}.
\end{align}
I think that
\begin{align}
r_{21}^0 = \tau_{12} r_{12}^0 \tau_{12}.
\end{align}
How to express $r_{21}^0$ using $H_{\alpha}$, $H_{\beta}$?

We have 
\begin{align}
& (\alpha \otimes 1)(r^0)   \\
& = (\alpha \otimes 1)(\frac{1}{3} H_{\alpha} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\beta}) \\
& = \frac{1}{3} \alpha(H_{\alpha}) \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} \alpha(H_{\beta}) \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} \alpha(H_{\beta}) \otimes H_{\beta}.
\end{align}
I think that $\alpha(H_{\alpha})=1$ and $\alpha(H_{\beta})=0$ (is this correct?). Then we have 
\begin{align}
& (\alpha \otimes 1)(r^0)   \\
& = (\alpha \otimes 1)(\frac{1}{3} H_{\alpha} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes H_{\beta}) \\
& = \frac{1}{3} \alpha(H_{\alpha}) \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} \alpha(H_{\beta}) \otimes H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} \alpha(H_{\beta}) \otimes H_{\beta} \\
& = .\frac{1}{3} \otimes H_{\alpha}. 
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
& (1 \otimes \beta)(r^0)   \\
& = .\frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes 1. 
\end{align}
But we do not have 
\begin{align}
(\alpha \otimes 1)(r^0) + (1 \otimes \beta)(r^0) = 0.
\end{align}
I think that I made some mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are simples not fundamentals so redo that $\alpha (H_\beta)$ step.

Comment: @AHusain, thank you very much. Since $\alpha = 2\omega_1-\omega_2$. $\beta = -\omega_1 + 2 \omega_2$, we have $\alpha(H_{\alpha}) = 2$, $\alpha(H_{\beta}) = -1$, $\beta(H_{\alpha})=-1$, $\beta(H_{\beta})=2$. Therefore $(\alpha \otimes 1)(r^0) = \frac{1}{3} \otimes H_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{3} \otimes H_{\beta}$, $(1 \otimes \beta)(r^0) = -\frac{1}{3} H_{\alpha} \otimes 1 + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta} \otimes 1$. But it seems that $H_{\alpha} \otimes 1 \neq 1 \otimes H_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @AHusain, I think that $(\alpha \otimes 1)(r^0) = \frac{1}{3} H_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta}$, $(1 \otimes \beta)(r^0) = -\frac{1}{3} H_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{3} H_{\beta}$. Therefore $ (\alpha \otimes 1)(r^0) + (1 \otimes \beta)(r^0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In the book,  a guide to quantum groups. I find a mistake,

the $H_{\alpha}$ should be defined $H_{\alpha}=E_{11}-E_{22}$.

The Casimir element
$t_{0}=\sum_{i}\frac{n}{n-1} E_{ii}\otimes E_{ii}-\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{1}{n}E_{ii}\otimes E_{jj}$.
 You can see the following paper for more detail.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9901079v3.pdf .